# How can i have a custom theme created by myself for multilingual site?

Tags: 7, theming, i18n-l10n

My website uses i8ln and it is configured to work with a large amount of languages. Using the page.tpl.php i managed to translate the website. But i had to create another custom theme for a specific path and the 404 page. So i created a page--node--23.tpl.php file and clear the cache. The file worked since the node i was trying to import the new theme was the node id defined when i created node/23. 
Now my problem is that i need to translate node/23 but when i click on translate and click save to save the translation another node is created and hence the page--node--23.tpl.php file is not used. How to set up drupal and able to adjust trasnaltion along with the custom themes???

Comment: Is it not possible to make use of node tpl and to theme you can throw in some conditions that checks for the specific paths.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean??

Comment: Instead of adding node-NUMBER.tpl make use of node.tpl.php(which will be used for all nodes) and add some conditions over there which will check for specific paths and theme accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Theming pages based on node id is not the way to handle this because you will have to copy each template to the corresponding translated nids. 
A better approach is to create content types based on differences (which can be different layouts as well). 
You can create a content type "404_page" for 404 pages in each language and create a template node--404_page.tpl.php to style them. This is all node specific.

There are also page specific overrides like:

page--front.tpl.php  
page--user.tpl.php  
page--blog.tpl.php

Edit: Some extra information on Theme hook suggestions can be found on the [Drupal 7 Theme Hook Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) documentation page.

Comment: So i have created the new content type called 404_page and created a page using that type. Also i created the node--404_page.tpl.php file and when i view the page  i still got the header and footer of the main pages. Using Firebug the body class is defined with: html not-front logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-893 node-type-404-page lang-en toolbar toolbar-drawer il8n-en show-grid ... Anyhow in my node--404_page.tpl.php file i have just only added the below code:

Comment: <div id="page" class="container_24 clearfix">

  <div id="layout" >
    <div id="main-layout">
        <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
     </div>
   </div>   

</div>'code' So why i am i stil getting the heater and footer?

Comment: That's because the header and the footer is rendered from the page.tpl.php template. Maybe you can unset the $header and $footer in the hook_preprocess_page($vars) if the $content contains a node of type 404_page.

Comment: You can check template files and preprocess functions using the http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer module.

Comment: I have read about unsetting css files but not how to unset regions. How am i going to accomplish that?

Comment: You do not have to unset a full region, only a variable coming from the hook_preprocess_page(&vars). Something like if($vars['page'][‘content']['type'] == 404_page) { unset($vars['page']['footer'] }

Comment: if($vars['page'][‘content']['type']) i dont think this is acceptable. It has been highlighted with red...are you sure this kind of code can be added to template.php file??

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4044/discussion-between-nicole-and-jurgenr)

Comment: Ok figured this out. In case anyone need this. What i did was to creare a new node type called 404_page. Created a file for the specific content type called node--404_page.tpl.php and added the code below.   
<div id="page" class="container_24 clearfix"> <div id="layout" > <div id="main-layout"> <?php print render($page['content']); ?> </div> </div> </div>. After that, I created another file called page--404.tpl.php. In my template php file i added these 2 lines and it works like a charm. if ($vars['node']->type == '404_page'){
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__404';
    }

Comment: Nice! I'm not familiar with overriding theme_hook-suggestions but seems like a perfect solution.